# LIBGDX MeshPartBuilder Texture only onecolored

Tags: colors, model, libgdx, textures, mesh

Well, I am using LIBGDX and a nice texture with a resolution of higher that FullHD, now I tried to add this texture to my model.

```
for (int i = 0; i < plB.size(); i++) {
        MeshPartBuilder builder = modelBuilder.part("part " + i, GL20.GL_TRIANGLES, VertexAttributes.Usage.Position | VertexAttributes.Usage.Normal, new Material(TextureAttribute.createDiffuse(type.getTexture())));

        int next = i < plB.size() - 1 ? i + 1 : 0;
        MeshPartBuilder.VertexInfo v1 = new MeshPartBuilder.VertexInfo().setPos(plB.get(i).x, plB.get(i).y, plB.get(i).z).setNor(0, 0, 1).setCol(null);
        MeshPartBuilder.VertexInfo v2 = new MeshPartBuilder.VertexInfo().setPos(plT.get(i).x, plT.get(i).y, plT.get(i).z).setNor(0, 0, 1).setCol(null);
        MeshPartBuilder.VertexInfo v3 = new MeshPartBuilder.VertexInfo().setPos(plT.get(next).x, plT.get(next).y, plT.get(next).z).setNor(0, 0, 1).setCol(null);
        MeshPartBuilder.VertexInfo v4 = new MeshPartBuilder.VertexInfo().setPos(plB.get(next).x, plB.get(next).y, plB.get(next).z).setNor(0, 0, 1).setCol(null);

        builder.rect(v1, v2, v3, v4);
    }
```

But it only looks green and ugly. What do I have to change?

Comment: you need to specify `Usage.TextureCoordinates` for the vertex attributes and specify the texture coordinate (UV) for each corner of the rectangle. Alternatively to the latter, just use the `rect` method which takes the coordinates of each corner instead of manually specifying each `VertexInfo`.

Comment: Well, it works a bit, but I'd like to use a texture for my whole model, is that somehow possible?

Comment: Yes, that's the same.